# Use of objects inside FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I've created a reactive form and It's working fine:

ts file:

```
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
  title:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] ],
  dateHour:[null, [Validators.required] ],
  description:[null, [Validators.required] ], 
  location: this.formBuilder.group({
            idLocation: [null],
            lat:[null],
            lng:[null],
  }),
});
```

After that, I've created a class for each one:

```
export class Ocr {
    idOcr: number;
    title: string;
    dateHour: Date;
    description: string;
    location: Location;
}

export class Location {
    idLocation: number;
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
}
```

Then, I've instanciated the object in the ts file and I would like to use the atributes in the FormBuilder. In this case, I don't know what write in the location atribute:

```
ocr: Ocr = new Ocr();

...

this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
  title:[this.ocr.title, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] ],
  dateHour:[this.ocr.DateHour, [Validators.required] ],
  description:[this.ocr.description, [Validators.required] ], 
  location: ??????? 
  }),
});
```

I would like to know how I have to represent it in the html file too.

Comment: What is the desired input from the user?

Comment: The user will input all of these information in a form. I would like to take advantage of this class to use as editing form as well

Comment: That makes sense. Specifically, what value will the user be keying in for location?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it, there is a textbox which the user write the location and I use a webservice to retrieve the lat/lng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new formGroup like so:

```
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
  title:[this.ocr.title, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] ],
  dateHour:[this.ocr.DateHour, [Validators.required] ],
  description:[this.ocr.description, [Validators.required] ], 
  location: this.formBuilder.group({
      lat:[this.ocr.location.lat, [Validators.required] ],
      lng:[this.ocr.location.lng, [Validators.required] ],
    })
  }),
});
```

Comment: how can I represent it in the html file?

Comment: I've written like you have recommended me but there is a error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Comment: For you first question: you need to wrap your location inputs inside a  formGroupName
`<form [formGroup]="formulario">
    <div formGroupName="location">
        <your location inputs>...
    </div>
</form>
`

Comment: And for your second question, you have a few options. One would be to create a constructor inside your Ocs class and initiate your location class there with default values